# Webdriver JAVA: How to use generated values(random values) from other class?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a registration process where I need to input nickname,email address and password.

As several registration tests needs to be done, I would like to define/customize parameters in another class and retrieve those in the present class whenever needed. Is this possible?

My question:

1.How do I retrieve parameters from another class?

2.I would like to declare and generate customized email address, customized nickname and static password for each and every registration. How do I do that?
   eg: nickname:  random alphanumeric(5 characters)
        email id: nickname_auto@hilton.il.net (@hilton.il.net is constant)
       Password : azerty8!(constant one)

Comment: What is a _constant parameter_? A constant value cannot be changed. A parameter can be changed. Additionally: This question is more about Java basics. So you should remove misleading tags about selenium/webdriver.

Comment: You should look up data driven testing using factory and dataprovider in testng. in junit you can use the parameterized runner class for this.